# Ajax function that works in Firefox but not in IE 6

Tags: ajax, jsp

i have a Ajax function that works in Firefox but not in IE 6

my ajax script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function actualiserDLIS(){
 var url = 'administration/gestionUtilisateurs.do?method=actualisationDLIs';
 var params =  'DR='+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('selectDR').value);
    var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(
            url, 
            {   method: 'post',
             parameters: params,
                onComplete: majDLIS
            });
}

function majDLIS(retour){
 if (retour.status == 200)
    {
        alert("Retour Status: "+retour.responseText);
        document.getElementById('tableDLI').innerHTML = retour.responseText;
    }else{
      document.getElementById('tableDLI').innerHTML = "uncool";
    }

}

</script>
```

in my `<body>`

[...]

```
<table class="tabForm" id="tableDLI">
   <c:forEach var="DLI"   items="${sessionScope['fiscalite.AdministrationGestionUtilisateurForm'].DLISUtilisateur}"  varStatus="status" >
      <tr>
         <td class="label_tableau_type1 width200px" ><c:out value="${DLI.code}"/>
         </td>            
      <td class="width150px" colspan="3"><html:checkbox property="DLI(${status.count-1})"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
       </c:forEach>
      </table>
```

[...]

in my alertI'm recovering well my data that I want to display in my `tableDLI`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're using Prototype. First I must mention that targeting IE6 is wrong, worse, it's evil. It's well known that this browser is broken in all sorts of ways. You probably have javascript errors in the browser, what are they?

[Here is a what can be a useful link](http://robsanheim.com/2005/10/11/prototype-insertion-ie-6-trs-and-invalid-target-element-for-this-operation/).

Comment: Could you publish a complete web page displaying the problem?